# One label for each contour line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-3.200,
    xmax=3.200,
    ymin=-3.200,
    ymax=3.200,
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids]
    \addplot[contour prepared, contour prepared format=matlab, line width=1.4pt] table[row sep=crcr] {
        -1.000  166.000\\
        3.200   -3.054\\
        3.147   -3.006\\
        3.135   -2.996\\
        3.075   -2.941\\
        3.071   -2.938\\
        3.006   -2.880\\
        3.002   -2.877\\
        2.941   -2.822\\
        2.930   -2.812\\
        2.877   -2.765\\
        2.857   -2.747\\
        2.812   -2.707\\
        2.785   -2.683\\
        2.747   -2.649\\
        2.712   -2.618\\
        2.683   -2.592\\
        2.639   -2.554\\
        2.618   -2.535\\
        2.566   -2.489\\
        2.554   -2.477\\
        2.494   -2.424\\
        2.489   -2.420\\
        2.424   -2.362\\
        2.421   -2.360\\
        2.360   -2.304\\
        2.349   -2.295\\
        2.295   -2.246\\
        2.277   -2.230\\
        2.230   -2.188\\
        2.205   -2.166\\
        2.166   -2.130\\
        2.133   -2.101\\
        2.101   -2.071\\
        2.062   -2.036\\
        2.036   -2.012\\
        1.992   -1.972\\
        1.972   -1.953\\
        1.922   -1.907\\
        1.907   -1.893\\
        1.852   -1.842\\
        1.842   -1.833\\
        1.784   -1.778\\
        1.778   -1.772\\
        1.716   -1.713\\
        1.713   -1.710\\
        1.649   -1.648\\
        1.648   -1.648\\
        1.584   -1.584\\
        1.584   -1.584\\
        1.520   -1.519\\
        1.519   -1.519\\
        1.457   -1.455\\
        1.455   -1.452\\
        1.396   -1.390\\
        1.390   -1.383\\
        1.336   -1.325\\
        1.325   -1.312\\
        1.279   -1.261\\
        1.261   -1.238\\
        1.224   -1.196\\
        1.196   -1.160\\
        1.172   -1.131\\
        1.131   -1.077\\
        1.123   -1.067\\
        1.077   -1.002\\
        1.067   -0.985\\
        1.035   -0.937\\
        1.002   -0.880\\
        0.998   -0.873\\
        0.964   -0.808\\
        0.937   -0.747\\
        0.936   -0.743\\
        0.912   -0.679\\
        0.894   -0.614\\
        0.883   -0.549\\
        0.877   -0.485\\
        0.877   -0.420\\
        0.882   -0.356\\
        0.893   -0.291\\
        0.909   -0.226\\
        0.930   -0.162\\
        0.937   -0.143\\
        0.955   -0.097\\
        0.984   -0.032\\
        1.002   0.003\\
        1.016   0.032\\
        1.051   0.097\\
        1.067   0.122\\
        1.089   0.162\\
        1.129   0.226\\
        1.131   0.229\\
        1.171   0.291\\
        1.196   0.328\\
        1.214   0.356\\
        1.259   0.420\\
        1.261   0.423\\
        1.304   0.485\\
        1.325   0.514\\
        1.350   0.549\\
        1.390   0.603\\
        1.397   0.614\\
        1.445   0.679\\
        1.455   0.691\\
        1.493   0.743\\
        1.519   0.778\\
        1.541   0.808\\
        1.584   0.865\\
        1.590   0.873\\
        1.638   0.937\\
        1.648   0.950\\
        1.687   1.002\\
        1.713   1.036\\
        1.736   1.067\\
        1.778   1.122\\
        1.785   1.131\\
        1.833   1.196\\
        1.842   1.208\\
        1.882   1.261\\
        1.907   1.294\\
        1.930   1.325\\
        1.972   1.380\\
        1.979   1.390\\
        2.027   1.455\\
        2.036   1.467\\
        2.075   1.519\\
        2.101   1.554\\
        2.123   1.584\\
        2.166   1.641\\
        2.171   1.648\\
        2.219   1.713\\
        2.230   1.728\\
        2.267   1.778\\
        2.295   1.816\\
        2.315   1.842\\
        2.360   1.903\\
        2.362   1.907\\
        2.410   1.972\\
        2.424   1.991\\
        2.457   2.036\\
        2.489   2.079\\
        2.505   2.101\\
        2.553   2.166\\
        2.554   2.166\\
        2.601   2.230\\
        2.618   2.254\\
        2.649   2.295\\
        2.683   2.341\\
        2.697   2.360\\
        2.745   2.424\\
        2.747   2.428\\
        2.793   2.489\\
        2.812   2.514\\
        2.842   2.554\\
        2.877   2.600\\
        2.890   2.618\\
        2.939   2.683\\
        2.941   2.685\\
        2.989   2.747\\
        3.006   2.770\\
        3.038   2.812\\
        3.071   2.854\\
        3.088   2.877\\
        3.135   2.937\\
        3.139   2.941\\
        3.189   3.006\\
        3.200   3.020\\
        -1.000  166.000\\
        -3.200  3.020\\
        -3.189  3.006\\
        -3.139  2.941\\
        -3.135  2.937\\
        -3.088  2.877\\
        -3.071  2.854\\
        -3.038  2.812\\
        -3.006  2.770\\
        -2.989  2.747\\
        -2.941  2.685\\
        -2.939  2.683\\
        -2.890  2.618\\
        -2.877  2.600\\
        -2.842  2.554\\
        -2.812  2.514\\
        -2.793  2.489\\
        -2.747  2.428\\
        -2.745  2.424\\
        -2.697  2.360\\
        -2.683  2.341\\
        -2.649  2.295\\
        -2.618  2.254\\
        -2.601  2.230\\
        -2.554  2.166\\
        -2.553  2.166\\
        -2.505  2.101\\
        -2.489  2.079\\
        -2.457  2.036\\
        -2.424  1.991\\
        -2.410  1.972\\
        -2.362  1.907\\
        -2.360  1.903\\
        -2.315  1.842\\
        -2.295  1.816\\
        -2.267  1.778\\
        -2.230  1.728\\
        -2.219  1.713\\
        -2.171  1.648\\
        -2.166  1.641\\
        -2.123  1.584\\
        -2.101  1.554\\
        -2.075  1.519\\
        -2.036  1.467\\
        -2.027  1.455\\
        -1.979  1.390\\
        -1.972  1.380\\
        -1.930  1.325\\
        -1.907  1.294\\
        -1.882  1.261\\
        -1.842  1.208\\
        -1.833  1.196\\
        -1.785  1.131\\
        -1.778  1.122\\
        -1.736  1.067\\
        -1.713  1.036\\
        -1.687  1.002\\
        -1.648  0.950\\
        -1.638  0.937\\
        -1.590  0.873\\
        -1.584  0.865\\
        -1.541  0.808\\
        -1.519  0.778\\
        -1.493  0.743\\
        -1.455  0.691\\
        -1.445  0.679\\
        -1.397  0.614\\
        -1.390  0.603\\
        -1.350  0.549\\
        -1.325  0.514\\
        -1.304  0.485\\
        -1.261  0.423\\
        -1.259  0.420\\
        -1.214  0.356\\
        -1.196  0.328\\
        -1.171  0.291\\
        -1.131  0.229\\
        -1.129  0.226\\
        -1.089  0.162\\
        -1.067  0.122\\
        -1.051  0.097\\
        -1.016  0.032\\
        -1.002  0.003\\
        -0.984  -0.032\\
        -0.955  -0.097\\
        -0.937  -0.143\\
        -0.930  -0.162\\
        -0.909  -0.226\\
        -0.893  -0.291\\
        -0.882  -0.356\\
        -0.877  -0.420\\
        -0.877  -0.485\\
        -0.883  -0.549\\
        -0.894  -0.614\\
        -0.912  -0.679\\
        -0.936  -0.743\\
        -0.937  -0.747\\
        -0.964  -0.808\\
        -0.998  -0.873\\
        -1.002  -0.880\\
        -1.035  -0.937\\
        -1.067  -0.985\\
        -1.077  -1.002\\
        -1.123  -1.067\\
        -1.131  -1.077\\
        -1.172  -1.131\\
        -1.196  -1.160\\
        -1.224  -1.196\\
        -1.261  -1.238\\
        -1.279  -1.261\\
        -1.325  -1.312\\
        -1.336  -1.325\\
        -1.390  -1.383\\
        -1.396  -1.390\\
        -1.455  -1.452\\
        -1.457  -1.455\\
        -1.519  -1.519\\
        -1.520  -1.519\\
        -1.584  -1.584\\
        -1.584  -1.584\\
        -1.648  -1.648\\
        -1.649  -1.648\\
        -1.713  -1.710\\
        -1.716  -1.713\\
        -1.778  -1.772\\
        -1.784  -1.778\\
        -1.842  -1.833\\
        -1.852  -1.842\\
        -1.907  -1.893\\
        -1.922  -1.907\\
        -1.972  -1.953\\
        -1.992  -1.972\\
        -2.036  -2.012\\
        -2.062  -2.036\\
        -2.101  -2.071\\
        -2.133  -2.101\\
        -2.166  -2.130\\
        -2.205  -2.166\\
        -2.230  -2.188\\
        -2.277  -2.230\\
        -2.295  -2.246\\
        -2.349  -2.295\\
        -2.360  -2.304\\
        -2.421  -2.360\\
        -2.424  -2.362\\
        -2.489  -2.420\\
        -2.494  -2.424\\
        -2.554  -2.477\\
        -2.566  -2.489\\
        -2.618  -2.535\\
        -2.639  -2.554\\
        -2.683  -2.592\\
        -2.712  -2.618\\
        -2.747  -2.649\\
        -2.785  -2.683\\
        -2.812  -2.707\\
        -2.857  -2.747\\
        -2.877  -2.765\\
        -2.930  -2.812\\
        -2.941  -2.822\\
        -3.002  -2.877\\
        -3.006  -2.880\\
        -3.071  -2.938\\
        -3.075  -2.941\\
        -3.135  -2.996\\
        -3.147  -3.006\\
        -3.200  -3.054\\
        1.000   150.000\\
        3.049   -3.200\\
        3.006   -3.164\\
        2.970   -3.135\\
        2.941   -3.111\\
        2.891   -3.071\\
        2.877   -3.059\\
        2.812   -3.007\\
        2.811   -3.006\\
        2.747   -2.955\\
        2.730   -2.941\\
        2.683   -2.904\\
        2.648   -2.877\\
        2.618   -2.853\\
        2.566   -2.812\\
        2.554   -2.802\\
        2.489   -2.752\\
        2.483   -2.747\\
        2.424   -2.702\\
        2.399   -2.683\\
        2.360   -2.653\\
        2.314   -2.618\\
        2.295   -2.604\\
        2.230   -2.555\\
        2.228   -2.554\\
        2.166   -2.506\\
        2.142   -2.489\\
        2.101   -2.458\\
        2.054   -2.424\\
        2.036   -2.411\\
        1.972   -2.364\\
        1.965   -2.360\\
        1.907   -2.317\\
        1.875   -2.295\\
        1.842   -2.271\\
        1.784   -2.230\\
        1.778   -2.226\\
        1.713   -2.180\\
        1.691   -2.166\\
        1.648   -2.136\\
        1.597   -2.101\\
        1.584   -2.092\\
        1.519   -2.048\\
        1.501   -2.036\\
        1.455   -2.005\\
        1.402   -1.972\\
        1.390   -1.963\\
        1.325   -1.922\\
        1.301   -1.907\\
        1.261   -1.881\\
        1.196   -1.842\\
        1.196   -1.842\\
        1.131   -1.803\\
        1.087   -1.778\\
        1.067   -1.766\\
        1.002   -1.729\\
        0.972   -1.713\\
        0.937   -1.694\\
        0.873   -1.660\\
        0.848   -1.648\\
        0.808   -1.628\\
        0.743   -1.597\\
        0.712   -1.584\\
        0.679   -1.568\\
        0.614   -1.541\\
        0.556   -1.519\\
        0.549   -1.517\\
        0.485   -1.494\\
        0.420   -1.473\\
        0.356   -1.456\\
        0.349   -1.455\\
        0.291   -1.441\\
        0.226   -1.428\\
        0.162   -1.419\\
        0.097   -1.413\\
        0.032   -1.410\\
        -0.032  -1.410\\
        -0.097  -1.413\\
        -0.162  -1.419\\
        -0.226  -1.428\\
        -0.291  -1.441\\
        -0.349  -1.455\\
        -0.356  -1.456\\
        -0.420  -1.473\\
        -0.485  -1.494\\
        -0.549  -1.517\\
        -0.556  -1.519\\
        -0.614  -1.541\\
        -0.679  -1.568\\
        -0.712  -1.584\\
        -0.743  -1.597\\
        -0.808  -1.628\\
        -0.848  -1.648\\
        -0.873  -1.660\\
        -0.937  -1.694\\
        -0.972  -1.713\\
        -1.002  -1.729\\
        -1.067  -1.766\\
        -1.087  -1.778\\
        -1.131  -1.803\\
        -1.196  -1.842\\
        -1.196  -1.842\\
        -1.261  -1.881\\
        -1.301  -1.907\\
        -1.325  -1.922\\
        -1.390  -1.963\\
        -1.402  -1.972\\
        -1.455  -2.005\\
        -1.501  -2.036\\
        -1.519  -2.048\\
        -1.584  -2.092\\
        -1.597  -2.101\\
        -1.648  -2.136\\
        -1.691  -2.166\\
        -1.713  -2.180\\
        -1.778  -2.226\\
        -1.784  -2.230\\
        -1.842  -2.271\\
        -1.875  -2.295\\
        -1.907  -2.317\\
        -1.965  -2.360\\
        -1.972  -2.364\\
        -2.036  -2.411\\
        -2.054  -2.424\\
        -2.101  -2.458\\
        -2.142  -2.489\\
        -2.166  -2.506\\
        -2.228  -2.554\\
        -2.230  -2.555\\
        -2.295  -2.604\\
        -2.314  -2.618\\
        -2.360  -2.653\\
        -2.399  -2.683\\
        -2.424  -2.702\\
        -2.483  -2.747\\
        -2.489  -2.752\\
        -2.554  -2.802\\
        -2.566  -2.812\\
        -2.618  -2.853\\
        -2.648  -2.877\\
        -2.683  -2.904\\
        -2.730  -2.941\\
        -2.747  -2.955\\
        -2.811  -3.006\\
        -2.812  -3.007\\
        -2.877  -3.059\\
        -2.891  -3.071\\
        -2.941  -3.111\\
        -2.970  -3.135\\
        -3.006  -3.164\\
        -3.049  -3.200\\
        1.000   174.000\\
        -3.030  3.200\\
        -3.006  3.173\\
        -2.972  3.135\\
        -2.941  3.100\\
        -2.915  3.071\\
        -2.877  3.027\\
        -2.858  3.006\\
        -2.812  2.953\\
        -2.802  2.941\\
        -2.747  2.879\\
        -2.745  2.877\\
        -2.689  2.812\\
        -2.683  2.805\\
        -2.633  2.747\\
        -2.618  2.730\\
        -2.577  2.683\\
        -2.554  2.656\\
        -2.521  2.618\\
        -2.489  2.581\\
        -2.465  2.554\\
        -2.424  2.507\\
        -2.409  2.489\\
        -2.360  2.432\\
        -2.352  2.424\\
        -2.296  2.360\\
        -2.295  2.358\\
        -2.239  2.295\\
        -2.230  2.284\\
        -2.183  2.230\\
        -2.166  2.211\\
        -2.125  2.166\\
        -2.101  2.138\\
        -2.068  2.101\\
        -2.036  2.065\\
        -2.010  2.036\\
        -1.972  1.994\\
        -1.951  1.972\\
        -1.907  1.923\\
        -1.892  1.907\\
        -1.842  1.853\\
        -1.832  1.842\\
        -1.778  1.784\\
        -1.772  1.778\\
        -1.713  1.716\\
        -1.710  1.713\\
        -1.648  1.649\\
        -1.648  1.648\\
        -1.584  1.584\\
        -1.584  1.584\\
        -1.519  1.520\\
        -1.519  1.519\\
        -1.455  1.457\\
        -1.452  1.455\\
        -1.390  1.395\\
        -1.384  1.390\\
        -1.325  1.336\\
        -1.314  1.325\\
        -1.261  1.277\\
        -1.241  1.261\\
        -1.196  1.221\\
        -1.166  1.196\\
        -1.131  1.166\\
        -1.088  1.131\\
        -1.067  1.114\\
        -1.007  1.067\\
        -1.002  1.063\\
        -0.937  1.014\\
        -0.920  1.002\\
        -0.873  0.968\\
        -0.827  0.937\\
        -0.808  0.924\\
        -0.743  0.883\\
        -0.726  0.873\\
        -0.679  0.844\\
        -0.614  0.809\\
        -0.613  0.808\\
        -0.549  0.775\\
        -0.485  0.746\\
        -0.479  0.743\\
        -0.420  0.719\\
        -0.356  0.696\\
        -0.297  0.679\\
        -0.291  0.677\\
        -0.226  0.661\\
        -0.162  0.649\\
        -0.097  0.641\\
        -0.032  0.637\\
        0.032   0.637\\
        0.097   0.641\\
        0.162   0.649\\
        0.226   0.661\\
        0.291   0.677\\
        0.297   0.679\\
        0.356   0.696\\
        0.420   0.719\\
        0.479   0.743\\
        0.485   0.746\\
        0.549   0.775\\
        0.613   0.808\\
        0.614   0.809\\
        0.679   0.844\\
        0.726   0.873\\
        0.743   0.883\\
        0.808   0.924\\
        0.827   0.937\\
        0.873   0.968\\
        0.920   1.002\\
        0.937   1.014\\
        1.002   1.063\\
        1.007   1.067\\
        1.067   1.114\\
        1.088   1.131\\
        1.131   1.166\\
        1.166   1.196\\
        1.196   1.221\\
        1.241   1.261\\
        1.261   1.277\\
        1.314   1.325\\
        1.325   1.336\\
        1.384   1.390\\
        1.390   1.395\\
        1.452   1.455\\
        1.455   1.457\\
        1.519   1.519\\
        1.519   1.520\\
        1.584   1.584\\
        1.584   1.584\\
        1.648   1.648\\
        1.648   1.649\\
        1.710   1.713\\
        1.713   1.716\\
        1.772   1.778\\
        1.778   1.784\\
        1.832   1.842\\
        1.842   1.853\\
        1.892   1.907\\
        1.907   1.923\\
        1.951   1.972\\
        1.972   1.994\\
        2.010   2.036\\
        2.036   2.065\\
        2.068   2.101\\
        2.101   2.138\\
        2.125   2.166\\
        2.166   2.211\\
        2.183   2.230\\
        2.230   2.284\\
        2.239   2.295\\
        2.295   2.358\\
        2.296   2.360\\
        2.352   2.424\\
        2.360   2.432\\
        2.409   2.489\\
        2.424   2.507\\
        2.465   2.554\\
        2.489   2.581\\
        2.521   2.618\\
        2.554   2.656\\
        2.577   2.683\\
        2.618   2.730\\
        2.633   2.747\\
        2.683   2.805\\
        2.689   2.812\\
        2.745   2.877\\
        2.747   2.879\\
        2.802   2.941\\
        2.812   2.953\\
        2.858   3.006\\
        2.877   3.027\\
        2.915   3.071\\
        2.941   3.100\\
        2.972   3.135\\
        3.006   3.173\\
        3.030   3.200\\
    };

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I used `matlab2tikz` to generate the plot (with some modifications). This is the result I get

[image]

How to tell `pgfplots` or `tikz` to limit contour label just one for each contour line (preferably close to the center of the line)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could play with `contour/label distance = x pt`, as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-3.200,
    xmax=3.200,
    ymin=-3.200,
    ymax=3.200,
    xmajorgrids,
    contour/label distance=160pt,
    ymajorgrids]
    \addplot[contour prepared, contour prepared format=matlab, line width=1.4pt] table[row sep=crcr] {
        -1.000  166.000\\
        3.200   -3.054\\
        3.147   -3.006\\
        3.135   -2.996\\
        3.075   -2.941\\
        3.071   -2.938\\
        3.006   -2.880\\
        3.002   -2.877\\
        2.941   -2.822\\
        2.930   -2.812\\
        2.877   -2.765\\
        2.857   -2.747\\
        2.812   -2.707\\
        2.785   -2.683\\
        2.747   -2.649\\
        2.712   -2.618\\
        2.683   -2.592\\
        2.639   -2.554\\
        2.618   -2.535\\
        2.566   -2.489\\
        2.554   -2.477\\
        2.494   -2.424\\
        2.489   -2.420\\
        2.424   -2.362\\
        2.421   -2.360\\
        2.360   -2.304\\
        2.349   -2.295\\
        2.295   -2.246\\
        2.277   -2.230\\
        2.230   -2.188\\
        2.205   -2.166\\
        2.166   -2.130\\
        2.133   -2.101\\
        2.101   -2.071\\
        2.062   -2.036\\
        2.036   -2.012\\
        1.992   -1.972\\
        1.972   -1.953\\
        1.922   -1.907\\
        1.907   -1.893\\
        1.852   -1.842\\
        1.842   -1.833\\
        1.784   -1.778\\
        1.778   -1.772\\
        1.716   -1.713\\
        1.713   -1.710\\
        1.649   -1.648\\
        1.648   -1.648\\
        1.584   -1.584\\
        1.584   -1.584\\
        1.520   -1.519\\
        1.519   -1.519\\
        1.457   -1.455\\
        1.455   -1.452\\
        1.396   -1.390\\
        1.390   -1.383\\
        1.336   -1.325\\
        1.325   -1.312\\
        1.279   -1.261\\
        1.261   -1.238\\
        1.224   -1.196\\
        1.196   -1.160\\
        1.172   -1.131\\
        1.131   -1.077\\
        1.123   -1.067\\
        1.077   -1.002\\
        1.067   -0.985\\
        1.035   -0.937\\
        1.002   -0.880\\
        0.998   -0.873\\
        0.964   -0.808\\
        0.937   -0.747\\
        0.936   -0.743\\
        0.912   -0.679\\
        0.894   -0.614\\
        0.883   -0.549\\
        0.877   -0.485\\
        0.877   -0.420\\
        0.882   -0.356\\
        0.893   -0.291\\
        0.909   -0.226\\
        0.930   -0.162\\
        0.937   -0.143\\
        0.955   -0.097\\
        0.984   -0.032\\
        1.002   0.003\\
        1.016   0.032\\
        1.051   0.097\\
        1.067   0.122\\
        1.089   0.162\\
        1.129   0.226\\
        1.131   0.229\\
        1.171   0.291\\
        1.196   0.328\\
        1.214   0.356\\
        1.259   0.420\\
        1.261   0.423\\
        1.304   0.485\\
        1.325   0.514\\
        1.350   0.549\\
        1.390   0.603\\
        1.397   0.614\\
        1.445   0.679\\
        1.455   0.691\\
        1.493   0.743\\
        1.519   0.778\\
        1.541   0.808\\
        1.584   0.865\\
        1.590   0.873\\
        1.638   0.937\\
        1.648   0.950\\
        1.687   1.002\\
        1.713   1.036\\
        1.736   1.067\\
        1.778   1.122\\
        1.785   1.131\\
        1.833   1.196\\
        1.842   1.208\\
        1.882   1.261\\
        1.907   1.294\\
        1.930   1.325\\
        1.972   1.380\\
        1.979   1.390\\
        2.027   1.455\\
        2.036   1.467\\
        2.075   1.519\\
        2.101   1.554\\
        2.123   1.584\\
        2.166   1.641\\
        2.171   1.648\\
        2.219   1.713\\
        2.230   1.728\\
        2.267   1.778\\
        2.295   1.816\\
        2.315   1.842\\
        2.360   1.903\\
        2.362   1.907\\
        2.410   1.972\\
        2.424   1.991\\
        2.457   2.036\\
        2.489   2.079\\
        2.505   2.101\\
        2.553   2.166\\
        2.554   2.166\\
        2.601   2.230\\
        2.618   2.254\\
        2.649   2.295\\
        2.683   2.341\\
        2.697   2.360\\
        2.745   2.424\\
        2.747   2.428\\
        2.793   2.489\\
        2.812   2.514\\
        2.842   2.554\\
        2.877   2.600\\
        2.890   2.618\\
        2.939   2.683\\
        2.941   2.685\\
        2.989   2.747\\
        3.006   2.770\\
        3.038   2.812\\
        3.071   2.854\\
        3.088   2.877\\
        3.135   2.937\\
        3.139   2.941\\
        3.189   3.006\\
        3.200   3.020\\
        -1.000  166.000\\
        -3.200  3.020\\
        -3.189  3.006\\
        -3.139  2.941\\
        -3.135  2.937\\
        -3.088  2.877\\
        -3.071  2.854\\
        -3.038  2.812\\
        -3.006  2.770\\
        -2.989  2.747\\
        -2.941  2.685\\
        -2.939  2.683\\
        -2.890  2.618\\
        -2.877  2.600\\
        -2.842  2.554\\
        -2.812  2.514\\
        -2.793  2.489\\
        -2.747  2.428\\
        -2.745  2.424\\
        -2.697  2.360\\
        -2.683  2.341\\
        -2.649  2.295\\
        -2.618  2.254\\
        -2.601  2.230\\
        -2.554  2.166\\
        -2.553  2.166\\
        -2.505  2.101\\
        -2.489  2.079\\
        -2.457  2.036\\
        -2.424  1.991\\
        -2.410  1.972\\
        -2.362  1.907\\
        -2.360  1.903\\
        -2.315  1.842\\
        -2.295  1.816\\
        -2.267  1.778\\
        -2.230  1.728\\
        -2.219  1.713\\
        -2.171  1.648\\
        -2.166  1.641\\
        -2.123  1.584\\
        -2.101  1.554\\
        -2.075  1.519\\
        -2.036  1.467\\
        -2.027  1.455\\
        -1.979  1.390\\
        -1.972  1.380\\
        -1.930  1.325\\
        -1.907  1.294\\
        -1.882  1.261\\
        -1.842  1.208\\
        -1.833  1.196\\
        -1.785  1.131\\
        -1.778  1.122\\
        -1.736  1.067\\
        -1.713  1.036\\
        -1.687  1.002\\
        -1.648  0.950\\
        -1.638  0.937\\
        -1.590  0.873\\
        -1.584  0.865\\
        -1.541  0.808\\
        -1.519  0.778\\
        -1.493  0.743\\
        -1.455  0.691\\
        -1.445  0.679\\
        -1.397  0.614\\
        -1.390  0.603\\
        -1.350  0.549\\
        -1.325  0.514\\
        -1.304  0.485\\
        -1.261  0.423\\
        -1.259  0.420\\
        -1.214  0.356\\
        -1.196  0.328\\
        -1.171  0.291\\
        -1.131  0.229\\
        -1.129  0.226\\
        -1.089  0.162\\
        -1.067  0.122\\
        -1.051  0.097\\
        -1.016  0.032\\
        -1.002  0.003\\
        -0.984  -0.032\\
        -0.955  -0.097\\
        -0.937  -0.143\\
        -0.930  -0.162\\
        -0.909  -0.226\\
        -0.893  -0.291\\
        -0.882  -0.356\\
        -0.877  -0.420\\
        -0.877  -0.485\\
        -0.883  -0.549\\
        -0.894  -0.614\\
        -0.912  -0.679\\
        -0.936  -0.743\\
        -0.937  -0.747\\
        -0.964  -0.808\\
        -0.998  -0.873\\
        -1.002  -0.880\\
        -1.035  -0.937\\
        -1.067  -0.985\\
        -1.077  -1.002\\
        -1.123  -1.067\\
        -1.131  -1.077\\
        -1.172  -1.131\\
        -1.196  -1.160\\
        -1.224  -1.196\\
        -1.261  -1.238\\
        -1.279  -1.261\\
        -1.325  -1.312\\
        -1.336  -1.325\\
        -1.390  -1.383\\
        -1.396  -1.390\\
        -1.455  -1.452\\
        -1.457  -1.455\\
        -1.519  -1.519\\
        -1.520  -1.519\\
        -1.584  -1.584\\
        -1.584  -1.584\\
        -1.648  -1.648\\
        -1.649  -1.648\\
        -1.713  -1.710\\
        -1.716  -1.713\\
        -1.778  -1.772\\
        -1.784  -1.778\\
        -1.842  -1.833\\
        -1.852  -1.842\\
        -1.907  -1.893\\
        -1.922  -1.907\\
        -1.972  -1.953\\
        -1.992  -1.972\\
        -2.036  -2.012\\
        -2.062  -2.036\\
        -2.101  -2.071\\
        -2.133  -2.101\\
        -2.166  -2.130\\
        -2.205  -2.166\\
        -2.230  -2.188\\
        -2.277  -2.230\\
        -2.295  -2.246\\
        -2.349  -2.295\\
        -2.360  -2.304\\
        -2.421  -2.360\\
        -2.424  -2.362\\
        -2.489  -2.420\\
        -2.494  -2.424\\
        -2.554  -2.477\\
        -2.566  -2.489\\
        -2.618  -2.535\\
        -2.639  -2.554\\
        -2.683  -2.592\\
        -2.712  -2.618\\
        -2.747  -2.649\\
        -2.785  -2.683\\
        -2.812  -2.707\\
        -2.857  -2.747\\
        -2.877  -2.765\\
        -2.930  -2.812\\
        -2.941  -2.822\\
        -3.002  -2.877\\
        -3.006  -2.880\\
        -3.071  -2.938\\
        -3.075  -2.941\\
        -3.135  -2.996\\
        -3.147  -3.006\\
        -3.200  -3.054\\
        1.000   150.000\\
        3.049   -3.200\\
        3.006   -3.164\\
        2.970   -3.135\\
        2.941   -3.111\\
        2.891   -3.071\\
        2.877   -3.059\\
        2.812   -3.007\\
        2.811   -3.006\\
        2.747   -2.955\\
        2.730   -2.941\\
        2.683   -2.904\\
        2.648   -2.877\\
        2.618   -2.853\\
        2.566   -2.812\\
        2.554   -2.802\\
        2.489   -2.752\\
        2.483   -2.747\\
        2.424   -2.702\\
        2.399   -2.683\\
        2.360   -2.653\\
        2.314   -2.618\\
        2.295   -2.604\\
        2.230   -2.555\\
        2.228   -2.554\\
        2.166   -2.506\\
        2.142   -2.489\\
        2.101   -2.458\\
        2.054   -2.424\\
        2.036   -2.411\\
        1.972   -2.364\\
        1.965   -2.360\\
        1.907   -2.317\\
        1.875   -2.295\\
        1.842   -2.271\\
        1.784   -2.230\\
        1.778   -2.226\\
        1.713   -2.180\\
        1.691   -2.166\\
        1.648   -2.136\\
        1.597   -2.101\\
        1.584   -2.092\\
        1.519   -2.048\\
        1.501   -2.036\\
        1.455   -2.005\\
        1.402   -1.972\\
        1.390   -1.963\\
        1.325   -1.922\\
        1.301   -1.907\\
        1.261   -1.881\\
        1.196   -1.842\\
        1.196   -1.842\\
        1.131   -1.803\\
        1.087   -1.778\\
        1.067   -1.766\\
        1.002   -1.729\\
        0.972   -1.713\\
        0.937   -1.694\\
        0.873   -1.660\\
        0.848   -1.648\\
        0.808   -1.628\\
        0.743   -1.597\\
        0.712   -1.584\\
        0.679   -1.568\\
        0.614   -1.541\\
        0.556   -1.519\\
        0.549   -1.517\\
        0.485   -1.494\\
        0.420   -1.473\\
        0.356   -1.456\\
        0.349   -1.455\\
        0.291   -1.441\\
        0.226   -1.428\\
        0.162   -1.419\\
        0.097   -1.413\\
        0.032   -1.410\\
        -0.032  -1.410\\
        -0.097  -1.413\\
        -0.162  -1.419\\
        -0.226  -1.428\\
        -0.291  -1.441\\
        -0.349  -1.455\\
        -0.356  -1.456\\
        -0.420  -1.473\\
        -0.485  -1.494\\
        -0.549  -1.517\\
        -0.556  -1.519\\
        -0.614  -1.541\\
        -0.679  -1.568\\
        -0.712  -1.584\\
        -0.743  -1.597\\
        -0.808  -1.628\\
        -0.848  -1.648\\
        -0.873  -1.660\\
        -0.937  -1.694\\
        -0.972  -1.713\\
        -1.002  -1.729\\
        -1.067  -1.766\\
        -1.087  -1.778\\
        -1.131  -1.803\\
        -1.196  -1.842\\
        -1.196  -1.842\\
        -1.261  -1.881\\
        -1.301  -1.907\\
        -1.325  -1.922\\
        -1.390  -1.963\\
        -1.402  -1.972\\
        -1.455  -2.005\\
        -1.501  -2.036\\
        -1.519  -2.048\\
        -1.584  -2.092\\
        -1.597  -2.101\\
        -1.648  -2.136\\
        -1.691  -2.166\\
        -1.713  -2.180\\
        -1.778  -2.226\\
        -1.784  -2.230\\
        -1.842  -2.271\\
        -1.875  -2.295\\
        -1.907  -2.317\\
        -1.965  -2.360\\
        -1.972  -2.364\\
        -2.036  -2.411\\
        -2.054  -2.424\\
        -2.101  -2.458\\
        -2.142  -2.489\\
        -2.166  -2.506\\
        -2.228  -2.554\\
        -2.230  -2.555\\
        -2.295  -2.604\\
        -2.314  -2.618\\
        -2.360  -2.653\\
        -2.399  -2.683\\
        -2.424  -2.702\\
        -2.483  -2.747\\
        -2.489  -2.752\\
        -2.554  -2.802\\
        -2.566  -2.812\\
        -2.618  -2.853\\
        -2.648  -2.877\\
        -2.683  -2.904\\
        -2.730  -2.941\\
        -2.747  -2.955\\
        -2.811  -3.006\\
        -2.812  -3.007\\
        -2.877  -3.059\\
        -2.891  -3.071\\
        -2.941  -3.111\\
        -2.970  -3.135\\
        -3.006  -3.164\\
        -3.049  -3.200\\
        1.000   174.000\\
        -3.030  3.200\\
        -3.006  3.173\\
        -2.972  3.135\\
        -2.941  3.100\\
        -2.915  3.071\\
        -2.877  3.027\\
        -2.858  3.006\\
        -2.812  2.953\\
        -2.802  2.941\\
        -2.747  2.879\\
        -2.745  2.877\\
        -2.689  2.812\\
        -2.683  2.805\\
        -2.633  2.747\\
        -2.618  2.730\\
        -2.577  2.683\\
        -2.554  2.656\\
        -2.521  2.618\\
        -2.489  2.581\\
        -2.465  2.554\\
        -2.424  2.507\\
        -2.409  2.489\\
        -2.360  2.432\\
        -2.352  2.424\\
        -2.296  2.360\\
        -2.295  2.358\\
        -2.239  2.295\\
        -2.230  2.284\\
        -2.183  2.230\\
        -2.166  2.211\\
        -2.125  2.166\\
        -2.101  2.138\\
        -2.068  2.101\\
        -2.036  2.065\\
        -2.010  2.036\\
        -1.972  1.994\\
        -1.951  1.972\\
        -1.907  1.923\\
        -1.892  1.907\\
        -1.842  1.853\\
        -1.832  1.842\\
        -1.778  1.784\\
        -1.772  1.778\\
        -1.713  1.716\\
        -1.710  1.713\\
        -1.648  1.649\\
        -1.648  1.648\\
        -1.584  1.584\\
        -1.584  1.584\\
        -1.519  1.520\\
        -1.519  1.519\\
        -1.455  1.457\\
        -1.452  1.455\\
        -1.390  1.395\\
        -1.384  1.390\\
        -1.325  1.336\\
        -1.314  1.325\\
        -1.261  1.277\\
        -1.241  1.261\\
        -1.196  1.221\\
        -1.166  1.196\\
        -1.131  1.166\\
        -1.088  1.131\\
        -1.067  1.114\\
        -1.007  1.067\\
        -1.002  1.063\\
        -0.937  1.014\\
        -0.920  1.002\\
        -0.873  0.968\\
        -0.827  0.937\\
        -0.808  0.924\\
        -0.743  0.883\\
        -0.726  0.873\\
        -0.679  0.844\\
        -0.614  0.809\\
        -0.613  0.808\\
        -0.549  0.775\\
        -0.485  0.746\\
        -0.479  0.743\\
        -0.420  0.719\\
        -0.356  0.696\\
        -0.297  0.679\\
        -0.291  0.677\\
        -0.226  0.661\\
        -0.162  0.649\\
        -0.097  0.641\\
        -0.032  0.637\\
        0.032   0.637\\
        0.097   0.641\\
        0.162   0.649\\
        0.226   0.661\\
        0.291   0.677\\
        0.297   0.679\\
        0.356   0.696\\
        0.420   0.719\\
        0.479   0.743\\
        0.485   0.746\\
        0.549   0.775\\
        0.613   0.808\\
        0.614   0.809\\
        0.679   0.844\\
        0.726   0.873\\
        0.743   0.883\\
        0.808   0.924\\
        0.827   0.937\\
        0.873   0.968\\
        0.920   1.002\\
        0.937   1.014\\
        1.002   1.063\\
        1.007   1.067\\
        1.067   1.114\\
        1.088   1.131\\
        1.131   1.166\\
        1.166   1.196\\
        1.196   1.221\\
        1.241   1.261\\
        1.261   1.277\\
        1.314   1.325\\
        1.325   1.336\\
        1.384   1.390\\
        1.390   1.395\\
        1.452   1.455\\
        1.455   1.457\\
        1.519   1.519\\
        1.519   1.520\\
        1.584   1.584\\
        1.584   1.584\\
        1.648   1.648\\
        1.648   1.649\\
        1.710   1.713\\
        1.713   1.716\\
        1.772   1.778\\
        1.778   1.784\\
        1.832   1.842\\
        1.842   1.853\\
        1.892   1.907\\
        1.907   1.923\\
        1.951   1.972\\
        1.972   1.994\\
        2.010   2.036\\
        2.036   2.065\\
        2.068   2.101\\
        2.101   2.138\\
        2.125   2.166\\
        2.166   2.211\\
        2.183   2.230\\
        2.230   2.284\\
        2.239   2.295\\
        2.295   2.358\\
        2.296   2.360\\
        2.352   2.424\\
        2.360   2.432\\
        2.409   2.489\\
        2.424   2.507\\
        2.465   2.554\\
        2.489   2.581\\
        2.521   2.618\\
        2.554   2.656\\
        2.577   2.683\\
        2.618   2.730\\
        2.633   2.747\\
        2.683   2.805\\
        2.689   2.812\\
        2.745   2.877\\
        2.747   2.879\\
        2.802   2.941\\
        2.812   2.953\\
        2.858   3.006\\
        2.877   3.027\\
        2.915   3.071\\
        2.941   3.100\\
        2.972   3.135\\
        3.006   3.173\\
        3.030   3.200\\
    };

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

The lower the distance, denser the labelling is.